# webscraping aspx with python and beautifulsoup results in html without info from original html

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i try to webscrape some data from an aspx-website:

https://firmen.berlin/sites/fitber/search/showDetails.aspx

The problem is, that the soup I generate, has not the information i need. I used the following Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
 
url = 'https://firmen.berlin/sites/fitber/search/defaultSearch.aspx'
url_get = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_get.content, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

I want to generate a List of the results from all the links in the original html, for example:

```
<a class="link-for-details" href="defaultSearch.aspx?SearchResult$Index=0">Züblin Spezialtiefbau GmbH Niederlassung Nord</a>
```

In my Soup i cant even see this Information, so I have difficulties to extract the infotmation. My soup looks like this:

```
</tr>
</table></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=PAq-a1as6t-LReK0Ct4W-a-FZXy55jP40uRx7Q6LRhJW2XWPBaE5o5LkeHDfHMhcfRQjpBE01XueKWdcLlg1A_aQI6me1x6xrA18XieG9iOnaJs-0&amp;t=637103382965614113"/></td><td nowrap="nowrap"><input id="ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_PanelLegalForm_DetailSearchLegalFormSwitcher_DetailSearchLegalForm2_TreeSelector_ctl12n58CheckBox" name="ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_PanelLegalForm_DetailSearchLegalFormSwitcher_DetailSearchLegalForm2_TreeSelector_ctl12n58CheckBox" type="checkbox"/><span id="ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_PanelLegalForm_DetailSearchLegalFormSwitcher_DetailSearchLegalForm2_TreeSelector_ctl12t58">UG (haftungsbeschränkt)</span></td>
</tr>
</table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><table width="20">
<tr>
```

Maybe someone knows how to transform the aspx in a good html-soup, so that i can extract the links.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: your question isn't clear for me at all

Comment: It looks links in defaultSearch.aspx are generated when a user preforms a search. That is, the user inputs some data & click a button. The page then does a post. Therefore you will need to mimic a post request with all the form data. Alternatively you could use a web scraping program like selenium

Comment: thanks Greg, it worked with selenium (see Answer)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with Selenium, here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd
import time 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/username/Anaconda3/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://firmen.berlin/sites/fitber/search/defaultSearch.aspx')

driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_CheckBoxPanel_CheckBoxAGB1").click();

driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_CheckBoxPanel_CheckBoxAGB2").click();

driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_CheckBoxPanel_ButtonConfirm").click();

driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_PanelTitleEmployee_Title").click();

driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_DetailSearchEmployeeSwitcher_DetailSearchEmployee2_TreeSelector_ctl06n9CheckBox").click();

driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_DetailSearchEmployeeSwitcher_DetailSearchEmployee2_TreeSelector_ctl06n10CheckBox").click();

driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_DetailSearchEmployeeSwitcher_DetailSearchEmployee2_TreeSelector_ctl06n11CheckBox").click();

driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_DetailSearchEmployeeSwitcher_DetailSearchEmployee2_TreeSelector_ctl06n12CheckBox").click();

driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_DetailSearchEmployeeSwitcher_DetailSearchEmployee2_TreeSelector_ctl06n13CheckBox").click();

driver.find_element(By.NAME, "ctl00$BodyPanel$ContentPanel$FitContent$SearchPanel$DetailSearchEmployeeSwitcher$DetailSearchEmployee2$TreeSelector$ctl10").click();

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_BodyPanel_ContentPanel_FitContent_SearchPanel_ButtonPanel_ButtonSearch").click();

company_name = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "link-for-details")

company_list = []
for p in range(len(company_name)):
    company_list.append(company_name[p].text)

print(company_list)
```